# CSS using percentage and margin, padding or border

Tags: css, border, margin, padding

I have a problem which I do not understand.
If I use percentage in width, I would expect that elements calculate borders, margins or paddings within their size (in percentage).
But in fact those values are added to their size which I asume is wrong.
Is my expectation wrong?
The bellow example shows the issue. The both "divs" "left" and "right" I expect to be in a single line. If I remove "border" it works as expected.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.center {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

.left {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
}

.right {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 80%;
  float: left;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="center">
  <div class="left">left</div>
  <div class="right">right</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's totally normal. It's not what you might expect at first, but CSS works that way.

Even without percentages:

```
#width {
    width: 100px;
    padding: 0 20px;
}
```

This #width div will occupy 140px. Works the same for percentages.

So you might need inner divs to achieve what you want.

```
<div class="left">
   <div class="inner">

   </div>
</div>
<div class="right">
   <div class="inner">
   </div>
</div>


.inner { padding: 10px; }
.right .inner { border-left: 1px solid #ccc; }
```

Answer (score 12):

What you can do to fix this issue is to use [box-sizing](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/box.html). See http://jsfiddle.net/Marwelln/YYkxK/

`box-sizing:border-box`

Comment: Doesn't work with Firefox 27 (the current version as of March 2014). Columns fall to two lines.

Answer (score 1):

Padding or Border always adds to an elements size, inside out.

Margin never adds to size but adds space outside the element.

Percentages or set values don't matter. The above is always true.

Reviewing the box model may help ---> [HERE](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html)

Answer (score 0):

When you use percentage as width (or height) values, these are the percentage of the width (or height) of the parent block element (containing block).

Answer (score 0):

In super modern browsers you can use calc() to fix this: calc(80% - 2px). And yes, it is normal. If you set the width to 100px and border to 150px what would happen then if border *wasnt* added?